# argument "env" is missing, with no default qplot or ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have a dataset with 3 columns for which I'm trying to plot the pdf for column ID. Here's what part of my data looks like.

```
        day          ID   count
        8754     48112050     1
        8975     48112050     3
        8327     61010046     2
        8346     61010046  3997
        8506     61010046     1
        8605     61010046     1
```

I use qplot for this :

```
qplot(count, colour=factor(ID), data=df, geom="density")
```

or ggplot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=count, colour= ID))+geom_density()
```

but it does not plot the pdf for all IDs. When I dig in, I realize that only IDs that have **no more** than 2 occurrences in my data are missing in the plot produced by qplot or ggplot. In this example, ID:48112050.

I plot the density for this ID only, and it works.

```
         day          ID   count
        8754     48112050     1
        8975     48112050     3
```

However, when I limit my df to just include this ID, or any ID with just 2 occurrences, the qplot or ggplot gives me the following error:

```
Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) : 
argument "env" is missing, with no default
```

Does this mean that qplot/ggplot needs at least 3 points to plot the density function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `ggplot2_1.0.1` does require at least three points to estimate a density. However, this behavior appears to have changed in the github repository with [this commit](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/commit/d58b00a58691e1b3753525759535d8abe942e304?diff=split#diff-d2084c2204ca3ec133d15fad9c40a119L104) on Jun 12,2015. There version that's currently on CRAN was published in March. I'm not sure when to expect the next release of `ggplot2`. You could try pulling the source directly from github if this behavior is essential to you,